# How can I optimize my routine to build HTML tiles from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

As my last question was closed for being "too vague" - here it is again, with better wording.

I have a "grid" of `li`'s that are loaded dynamically (through JavaScript/jQuery), the Array isn't huge but seems to take forever loading.

So, SO people - my question is:
Am I being stupid or is this code taking longer than it should to execute?

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/PrPvM/
(very slow, may appear to hang your browser)

**Full code (download):** http://www.mediafire.com/?xvd9tz07h2u644t

**Snippet (from the actual array loop):**

```
var gridContainer = $('#container');
    var gridArray = [ 
        2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    ];

    function loadMap() {
        var i = 0;
        while (i <= gridArray.length) {
            var gridHTML = $(gridContainer).html();
            $(gridContainer).html(gridHTML+'<li class="node"></li>');
            i++;
        }
        $('li.node').each(function() {
            $(gridArray).each(function (i, val) {
                if (val == '0') { gridTile = 'grass.jpg' };
                if (val == '1') { gridTile = 'mud.jpg' };
                if (val == '2') { gridTile = 'sand.gif' };
                $($('ul#container :nth-child('+i+')'))
                  .css({ 'background-image': 'url(img/tiles/'+gridTile });
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just a small tip, people will be more willing to view an example URL than download a file.

Comment: I posted a question with an example URL (from jsfiddle) - but it got closed and downvoted 4 times in less than a minute.

Comment: Yes @Tom it turns out that Stackoverflow wasn't feeling very good about example URLs today :-)

Comment: @Pointy: Example URLs that *demonstrate* the problem are fine - but readers shouldn't need to navigate away to find the relevant code. If nothing else, such things make the question nearly useless for future readers, who have to contend with broken links...

Comment: To be fair, my example URL did show the problem. I included a zip file link for ease of use (as stated) as well. You SO goblins just don't like me :(

Comment: @Neurofluxation: no, I mean the relevant code needs to be in *the question text itself*, as you've done above - if I'm reading SO on my phone (as I so often do), a zip link is useless! But more importantly, your question will be here for years to come - other people will find it and read it, and without the code, they're gonna be plenty confused...

Comment: ah, I getcha - np - future reference :)

Comment: @Shog9 True enough, but nobody even bothered to explain that to @Neurofluxation. I have no problem with closing bad questions as a way to improve site quality, but if that really is the goal we have to be clear about reasons for closing.

Comment: @Pointy: yeah, that's why I commented here - I'm glad he reposted the question with inline code, but don't want him (or anyone else) to get the impression that *examples* are somehow bad.

Comment: @Pointy and @Shog9 - Thank you, I appreciate your thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The loop where you set the background images is the real problem.  Look at it: you're looping through all the `<li>` elements that you just got finished building from the "grid".  Then, inside that loop — that is, for *each* `<li>` element — you go through the *entire* "grid" array and reset the background. Each node will end up being set <strike>to the exact same thing: the background corresponding to the last thing in the array</strike> over and over again to the exact same background.

The way you build the HTML is also very inefficient. You should loop through the grid and build up a string array with an `<li>` element in each array slot. Actually, now that I think of it, you really should be doing the first and second loops at the same time.

```
function loadMap() {
  var html = [], bg = ['grass', 'mud', 'sand'];
  for (var i = 0, len = gridArray.length; i < len; ++i) {
    html.push("<li class='node " + bg[gridArray[i]] + "'></li>");
  }
  $(gridContainer).html(html.join(''));
}
```

Now you'll also need some CSS rules:

```
li.grass { background-image: url(grass.jpg); }
li.mud { background-image: url(mud.jpg); }
li.sand { background-image: url(sand.gif); }
```

Comment: I don't suppose you would have any idea on how I could merge the two loops together?

Comment: Give me a sec and I'll type it in :-)

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph: he won't use the same background for every node, because the selector used to set the background relies on `nth-child` to pick the correct one. The outer loop - the one looping over `li.node`s - serves no purpose other than to make this exponentially slower... Your code side-steps all of these problems (and more) - nice work.

Comment: Ah - you're right; it *will* repeat the .css call for each one, but they'll get the right value. I'll fix my answer - thanks!!

Comment: Omg, pure genius! Excellent work Pointy - That has sped up my code like crazy!

Answer (score 3):

It'd probably be farm more efficient to build up the complete HTML for the array and *then* assign it to the `.html` property of the container, rather than assigning each individual `li`:

```
    var gridHTML = $(gridContainer).html();
    while (i <= gridArray.length) {
       gridHTML = gridHTML+'<li class="node"></li>';
        i++;
    }
    $(gridContainer).html();
```

---

Next, why are you looping over both of these? The outer loop is probably completely unnecessary, because your inner loop already uses `nth-child` to select the proper node.

```
    $('li.node').each(function() {
        $(gridArray).each(function (i, val) {
```